# How do I add an extension for XCUIElement?

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I am new to UI testing and xcode/ios development in general. How do I add extensions that hold methods that can be called within UI test targets?

This is a SAMPLE extension I'd like to add:

```
extension XCUIElement {
    /**
     Removes any current text in the field before typing in the new         
     value
   - Parameter text: the text to enter into the field
    */
    func clearAndEnterText(text: String) {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string     
            value")
            return
    }

        self.tap()

        let deleteString = stringValue.characters.map { _ in     
        XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete }.joined(separator: "")

        self.typeText(deleteString)
        self.typeText(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know where in this that it explains the question I'm asking.

Comment: Did you even read my question? The clearAndEnterText is from the extension. Please, read my question and let me know where in that thread my answer lies.

Comment: I got help on Reddit, specifically /r/iosprogramming. For anyone else wondering, the answer on how to add an extension for XCUIElement is under the testing target, right click and add a new swift file. Then import XCTest. Then copy the code you want to add, for example the extension above. Then you should be able to call any methods from extensions you add in files within that target.